# Executing Insert into statement in SQL resulting in nulls for other columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i am trying to use an insert into a column where the data for other columns already exists, but the data is not populating adjacent to the other columns, instead data is inserted after all the data in the table.
For example:

```
select * from tab1;       
ID NAme Last_name          
1  King                     
2  Queen                   
3  Rook 

select * from tab2;
Id LastName_Name
1  Abc 
2  def
3  xyz

SQL : Insert into tab1 (Last_name)
select tab2.LastName_Name from tab1,tab2, where tab1.Id=tab2.Id

Output:
Id Name Last_Name
1  King   NULL
2  Queen  NULL
3  Rook   NULL
4  NULL   Abc
5  NULL   def
6  NULL   xyz
```

But I want the data as below:

```
Id Name Last_Name
1  King   Abc
2  Queen  def
3  Rook   xyz
```

Any work around for this? thanks in advance :)

Step2:

select * from tab1;

ID Name   Id2

1  King    NA

2  Queen   NA

3  Rook    NA

select * from tab2;

```
ID 

1  

2  

3  

4

5

6
```

I want the Output data as below:

The ID data in tab2 should populate in tab1 column (ID2) which are matching with TAB1.ID column values as below:

```
Id Name ID2
1  King   1
2  Queen  2
3  Rook   3
```

Can you please provide any query for this?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOU ANSWER THAT HELPED ME AND WHAT SHOULD I  QUERY IF WANT TO DO THE BELOW:

select * from tab1;

ID NAme TAB2_ID

1 King

2 Queen

3 Rook

Exa:

select * from tab2;

Id 

1 

2 

3

OUTPUT:

ID NAme TAB2_ID

1 King   1

2 Queen  2

3 Rook   3

Comment: It's difficult to read when further questions are added as comments. Formatting really helps us to help you and as it's a different question, best thing to do is close this one off (accept the answer that solved the initial problem for you) and then open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

So you are wanting to UPDATE the rows in tab1 with the corresponding last names from tab2?

In which case, use an UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT:

```
UPDATE tab1
SET tab1.Last_name = tab2.LastName_Name
FROM tab1
    JOIN tab2 ON tab1.Id = tab2.Id
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOU ANSWER AND WHAT SHOULD I  QUERY IF WANT TO DO THE BELOW:

select * from tab1;

ID NAme TAB2_ID

1 King

2 Queen

3 Rook

Exa:

select * from tab2;

Id 

1 

2 

3

OUTPUT:

ID NAme TAB2_ID

1 King   1

2 Queen  2

3 Rook   3

Comment: @AdaTheDev
THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOU ANSWER AND WHAT SHOULD I QUERY IF WANT TO DO THE BELOW: select * from tab1;
 ID NAme TAB2_ID 
 1 King
 2 Queen
 3 Rook 

select * from tab2; 
Id 
 1
 2
 3
 OUTPUT:
 ID NAme TAB2_ID
 1 King 1 
 2 Queen 2 
 3 Rook 3

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `INSERT` you need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET tab1.Last_name = tab2.LastName_Name
FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.Id = tab2.Id
```

Comment: I WANT TO INSERT TAB2.ID INTO THE TAB1.TAB2_ID(COLUMN) FROM TAB2.ID
The out put should be :
ID NAME TAB2_ID
1  King   1

2  Queen  2

3  Rook   3
Please help

Comment: When i use the updates statement it is giving too many rows retireved

Comment: update your original question with this next step to make it clearer

Comment: @@AdaTheDev Hey Query Got worked that update system, i need to keep ltrim(id) for my results to get effected as the Id column in my table starts with a "Space".. Thank you very much